# How do I import domains into a feature class from a table in ArcGIS 10.2.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, domains

I have a table in a geodatabse which contains coded domain values.

I also have a feature class in the same geodatabase where I'd like to load those domain values.

There are hundreds of codes so I want to automate this process.

I've looked at the docs for [Table To Domain](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001700000025000000) to no avail. The issue is that after I run Table To Domain and select to output to the geodatabase of interest, I don't know what to do next. The result of running the tool seems to be nothing.

Is there anyway to load the coded values from a table (or an excel spreadsheet) into the domains of a feature class? You can see a sample of my workflow below.

[image]

Comment: What do your geoprocessing results tell you after you've run Table to Domain? You can check this by clicking on the Geoprocessing dropdown menu and selecting Results. Are there any relevant messages?

Comment: "Table To Domain" is your answer as you have mentioned in your question. what is the result of the geoprocessing when you run the tool? and what is the type of your table (dbf, excel...)?

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else with this issue, my environment was set incorrectly. The domain from the table data was being created in the Default.gdb. You change the domain temporarily with the 'Environments' button at the bottom of the tool window; or permanently by changing the default geodatabase for that particular map document.

Comment: Table to Domain will also throw an error if you have duplicate entries within the table you are trying to import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading domains that are already in a geodatabase onto a feature class in the same geodatabase is accomplished using the [Assign Domain to Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00170000001w000000) tool.